# Как извлечь содержимое тега при помощи lxml

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml

```
    aaa = '''
<ul><a href="http://test.ru/12345" >test1</a></ul>
<ul><a href="http://test.ru/56789" >test2</a></ul>
<ul><a href="http://test.ry/34567" >test3</a></ul>
'''
```

Как извлечь при помощи lxml из строки содержимое тегов `<ul>`.
Тоесть на выходе хотелось бы получить:

```
<a href="http://test.ru/12345" >test1</a>
<a href="http://test.ru/56789" >test2</a>
<a href="http://test.ry/34567" >test3</a>
```

Comment: Если нет проблем с английским, то тут подробно все расписано. http://lxml.de/parsing.html#parsers

Comment: Ознакомился, появился новый вопрос.  Как мне конвертировать вывод "<Element ul at 0xafc0a694>" в нормальное значение.

Answer (score 1):

Например, а более подробно смотреть в документации приведенных модулей.

Входные данные:

```
text = '''<div>
<ul><a href="http://test.ru/12345" >test1</a></ul>
<ul><a href="http://test.ru/56789" >test2</a></ul>
<ul><a href="http://test.ry/34567" >test3</a></ul>
</div>
'''
```

#### Решение через `lxml` (только с `tostring` получится получить HTML):

```
# pip install lxml
from lxml import etree

root = etree.fromstring(text)
items = root.xpath('//a')
print(items)
print('href:', items[0].attrib['href'])
print('tag:', etree.tostring(items[0], encoding='unicode'))
print()
for a in items:
    print('a:', etree.tostring(a, encoding='unicode'))
print()
print()
```

Консоль:

```
[<Element a at 0x2dae708>, <Element a at 0x2dae748>, <Element a at 0x2dae788>]
href: http://test.ru/12345
tag: <a href="http://test.ru/12345">test1</a>

a: <a href="http://test.ru/12345">test1</a>
a: <a href="http://test.ru/56789">test2</a>
a: <a href="http://test.ry/34567">test3</a>
```

---

#### Решение через `bs4` (достаточно запросить текстовое представление):

```
# pip install bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
root = BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml')
items = root.select('a')
print(items)

a = items[0]
print('href:', a['href'])
print('tag:', a)
```

Консоль:

```
[<a href="http://test.ru/12345">test1</a>, <a href="http://test.ru/56789">test2</a>, <a href="http://test.ry/34567">test3</a>]
href: http://test.ru/12345
tag: <a href="http://test.ru/12345">test1</a>
```

Comment: Как конвертировать [<Element a at 0xc72968>, <Element a at 0xc72990>, <Element a at 0xc729b8>] в [<a href="http://test.ru/12345">test1</a>, <a href="http://test.ru/56789">test2</a>, <a href="http://test.ry/34567">test3</a>] при использовании первого варианта (без BeautifulSoup) ?

Comment: @leonidtime, руками, но это просто разное представление, возвращенное из методов `__str__` / `__repr__`, так что в обоих вариантах внутренное представление одинаковое. Добавил в ответе примеры ;)

Comment: Плохо знаю объектно-ориентированное программирование, можно по подробнее как получить именно "<a href="test.ru/56789">test2</a>, а не <Element a at 0xc72968>

Comment: @leonidtime, используйте `etree.tostring`, в этом вопросе знание ООП вообще не влияет, нужно просто открыть документацию и посмотреть примеры

Comment: Благодарю, все получилось

Answer (score 0):

Вот что у меня получилось:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring

    aaa = '''
    <ul><a href="http://test.ru/12345" >test1</a></ul>
    <ul><a href="http://test.ru/56789" >test2</a></ul>
    <ul><a href="http://test.ry/34567" >test3</a></ul>

    '''

    html =  fromstring(aaa)
    a = html.xpath("//ul")
    print(a)
```

Результат:

```
[<Element ul at 0xafc0a694>, <Element ul at 0xb705ddec>, <Element ul at 0xafba9324>]
```

Как мне 
`[<Element ul at 0xafc0a694>, <Element ul at 0xb705ddec>, <Element ul at 0xafba9324>]`
Превратить в

```
[<a href="http://test.ru/12345" >test1</a>, <a href="http://test.ru/56789" >test2</a>, <a href="http://test.ry/34567" >test3</a>]
```